# passing linkedlist and get value of it

Tags: c

I am very sorry for the confusing code, so I am trying to change the whole question so it is impler :

So basically, I have a predefined struct that I get from a header file, that I put in one main file. 
I need to create a function that can take the value of value1->identity in my own function.

I am not supposed to pass the value1 as a parameter, as I can access value1 from user struct. 
but how can i do this in int funct(user *user) so when I print value1->identity in int funct(user *user) it does not return me a garbage value.

Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    int identity;
} value;

typedef struct list1_struct {
    value value1;
    struct list1_struct *next, *prev;
} list_t_slot;

typedef struct {
    list_t_slot *head, *tail;
} list_t;

typedef struct {
    int number;
    list_t value1s;
} value2;

typedef struct list2 {
    value2 conn;
    struct list2 *next, *prev;
} list_t_slot2;

typedef struct {
    list_t_slot2 *head, *tail;
} list_t2;

typedef struct {
    int power;
    list_t2 connections;
} user;

int funct(user *user) {

    return 1;
}

int main() {
    user user;
    memset(&user, 0, sizeof(user));

    list_t_slot2 chron_slot;
    memset(&chron_slot, 0, sizeof(chron_slot));
    value2 *conn = &chron_slot.conn;

    list_t_slot value1_slot;
    memset(&value1_slot, 0, sizeof(value1_slot));
    value *value1 = &value1_slot.value1;

    user.power = 1;
    value1->identity = 1;

    printf("value of identity is %d\n", value1->identity);

    funct(&user);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: BTW, its good habit to try and reduce an example to its most basic expression showing the problem or question.  You might also want to simplify the names used in vars/functions.  your example is very hard to follow.  its even hard to understand what its trying to do... this will definitely impact how many people attempt to help you, and the quality of the help they can give you.

Comment: halo @moliad, I already change it to a more simpler code.. I hope I can get a better explanataion

Answer (score 1):

Did you notice that you are not using the `user` variable until the end of `funct`?

You are working with uninitialized pointers. That's why you are getting different (all equally garbage) results. You have to fix this first.

To begin with:

```
chron_apn_con_list_t_slot *chron_slot;
chron_apn_con_t *conn = &chron_slot->conn;
```

This doesn't make any sense. There is no `chron_slot` object to work with. You either need to allocate one with a `malloc` or use a stack object by omitting the pointer notation when declaring `chron_slot`.

Comment: I am really sorry but I don't understand about this. I will finish the function by assigning user->power later on the function. but for now, I need to print the chroneval->identity so it gives me the correct result. (so this is just a draft-function) @junjanes

Comment: Thank you for your comment @junjanes. Yes, I made a big mistake for that part, so I change the code (updated) to use chron_slot as object of struct. But it still return me some random address. Do you have any further idea to fix this?

Comment: Yes, you still do not initialize it. Do you have an idea on what chron_slot would contain? If yes, it doesn't contain that.

Comment: honestly, now I totally more lost.. :(

Comment: It may be better if you add your intent to the question. What problem is this piece of code supposed to solve? Otherwise there is no telling what the correction would be.

Comment: sorry for the confussion. I change the question so it will be way simpler.. I hope I can get a tips for this. thank you